# CardAdapter jumps automatically when a request is sent to load image

Tags: java, android, rest, android-layout, android-asynctask

I'm trying to implement an IM-like application, but I get stuck on problem which really annoys me.

I use `recyclerview` to show messages in a scrolling manner, so that users can scroll the views to see all of the messages. Messages' base layout is a `cardview`
 widget.

Additionally, I've use another layout within the Messages' layout which is also a `cardview` to show sub-messages.

To be more detailed, I would like to visualize the layouts which I used. Look at the following picture:

[image: Layouts]

As you see I use two nested cardviews (inside each other). Moreover, as I use `recyclerview` for sub-messages, I have scrolling behavior. When I scroll sub-messages, the onBindViewHolder method of recyclerview is called. To retrieve each image, I call an API in onBindViewHolder method.

Now the problem arises when I want scroll the sub-messages. It seems that when the API is called something goes wrong. Although the image is retrieved successfully from API, it jumps down and up screen.

For example, If I scroll last message's sub-messages to the right. It ends up with the following result:

[image]

This is the `onBindViewHolder()` method of sub messages adapted, for working with the images, I use Glide android library:

```
public class SubMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubMenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    .
    .
    .
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SubMessage subMessage = subMessageList.get(position);
        final long mediaFileId = subMessage.getMediaFileId();
        holder.ivSubmessageImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        if (mediaFileId != 0) {
            holder.ivSubmessageImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                holder.ivSubmessageImage.setMinimumHeight(100);
                holder.ivSubmessageImage.setMinimumWidth(200);
                Glide.with(context).load(Config.FILE_SERVER_URL+"api/file/" + mediaFileId + "/thumb")
                        .into(holder.ivSubmessageImage);
                holder.ivSubmessageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } else {
                holder.ivSubmessageImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                holder.ivSubmessageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }
    ...

    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This is the layouts which I've created (at the moment):

**channel_log_list.xml** *(msgCardview)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/chatMsgBg"
    android:id="@+id/channelLogCard"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ivMessageImage"/>

                <com.example.TextViewPlus
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="messages"
                    app:customFont="@string/irs"
                    android:id="@+id/channelLogAppletTitle"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size_small2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lstSubMessages"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**sub_message_list_item.xml** *(subMsgCardview)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    style="@style/SubMessageCardViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/SubMessageCard">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivSubMessageImage"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <com.example.TextViewPlus
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            app:customFont="@string/irs"
            android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size_small1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I am having this issue. Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: Yes! I used Fresco library instead of Android's native elements. I also recommend you to use as it provides some interesting options for working with images :) it is definitely worth it @dazza5000

Comment: I am using Glide though...

Answer (score 0):

make your Cardview `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"  or make that layout which you want to focus`

Comment: Look I think the problem can be come from requesting methods. Do you have any opinion about it? @NileshRathod